# How is handle ordering of messages during failures at consumption end because of poison pill?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a basic question w.r.t how we can solve out of order messages at consumers end. On the producer, we can solve it using a single partition or partition key and route the messages to a specific partition. We got a poison pill message and the consumer it failing to process this record.

1. If we ignore and proceed we will lose the ordering.
2. If we process the same message then we will block it from processing other messages.

How to solve this issues?

Comment: Why would ignoring/skipping a record that's not able to be processed affect ordering?

Comment: Good point. ignoring or skipping is fine for poison pull. The same pattern will be applied for other failures as well which cause out of order.

Comment: Why this message is poison pill, what exception it's causing? it's better to handle and investigate the cause of issue. This case could repeat again. i don't see this can be skipped, basically how you are identifying this to be skipped in program.

Answer (score 0):

bring down the consumer and reset offset to (current offset + 1) via cli, this will skip poison pill message.

eg:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --group my-group --reset-offsets --shift-by 1 --topic sales_topic --execute
```

Comment: There's no guarantee the next message will be successful